# The Lerch transcendent evaluation for the parameters HurwitzLerchPhi[z,-4 s,0]

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, special-functions, upper-lower-bounds

I want to evaluate the  Hurwitz zeta function
$$ \Phi (z, -4s, 0)= \sum_{k=0} \frac{z^k}{k^{-4s}}$$
And $|z|<1$ and $s>1$.
I want to have un upper bound for it.
I tried even Wolfram Mathematica (to have some hint of the form if possible fot the calculus) , but without success (since I give parameters and no numbers as an input).

Comment: There is a relation to the polylogarithm: $\Phi(z,-4s,0) = \mathrm{Li}_{-4s}(z),$ but what exactly is your question.

Comment: I don't think an upper bound exists. For $z=1$ the series diverges, which means that for any $N$ we can find $\epsilon>0$ such that $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} (1-\epsilon)^k >N$$ For example for $s=1$ and $z=0.999$ the series converges to $2.394 \cdot 10^{16}$, and the closer $z$ to $1$ the larger the result will be

Comment: But |z|<1 in this case, and if you use the ratio criterium the ratio is smaller that one which means that the series is convergent..Thus, I was hoping some upper bound is possible to obtain. So to answer also the gammamaster's question, I want an upper bound for the series defined by $\Phi(z,-4s, 0).$

Comment: @Anne, my comment was stating that for $|z|<1$ the upper bound doesn't exist. I tried to show it more or less rigorously. According to the definition of the upper bound of a function, this function simply doesn't have it.

Comment: Take for example $ s=5/4$. Then 
$$\phi(x,-5,0) = \mathrm{Li}_{-5}(x) =
\frac{(1+26 x+66 x^2+26 x^3+x^4)x}{(x-1)^6} $$
Since the numerator is positive for $x>0$ you have a pole of order 6.

Comment: @YuriyS, thanks for the clarification, I see it now. Yes, you're right, thank you a lot for this comment, it will stop me for trying different approaches!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP is asking about the upper bound of the function:

$$\Phi (z, -4s, 0)= \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} z^k$$

$$|z|<1 \qquad s>1$$

First, it's obvious that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} z^k \leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} |z|^k$$

So let us consider only $z>0$.

For a fixed $z$ we can see that:

$$p>q \\ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4p} z^k>\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4q} z^k$$

Which means that if an upper bound exists for $\Phi$ as a function of $s$, it will be the limit:

$$\lim_{s \to +\infty} \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} z^k = \infty$$

---

Now let us fix a finite $s$ and see what happens for $z \to 1$. For $z=1$ the series obviously diverges, which automatically means that for $z$ close to $1$ the value can be as large as we want, which means there's no upper bound for a fixed $s$ either.

More rigorously, we need to prove that for any $N>0$ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that:

$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} (1-\epsilon)^k > N$$

It's rather easy, we can just compare to geometric series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{4s} (1-\epsilon)^k>\sum_{k=1}^\infty (1-\epsilon)^k=\frac{1-\epsilon}{\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1$$

Now pick $\epsilon=\frac{1}{N+1}$ and the proof is finished.