# Function upper-bounding polylogarithm function when $0 < z < 1$

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, polylogarithm

The [polylogarithm function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm) (aka Jonquière's function) is defined as $Li_s(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} z^k k^{-s}$.

Is there a closed-form upper bound for this function when $s \leq -1$ and is real, and $z \in [0, 1]$ and is also real?

Note: [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741061) is similar but the OP was looking for a constant bound, which is not possible. I am looking for an upper bound as a function of $z$ and $s$.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how good the upper bound needs to be, but one approach would be to start by noticing that if $s\leq t$ then
$$ z^kk^{-s}  \geq z^kk^{-t}$$
since $k\geq 1$. This means
$$ Li_s(z) \geq Li_t(z),$$
hence in particular
$$ Li_s(z) \leq Li_{\lfloor s\rfloor}(z)$$
since $\lfloor s\rfloor \leq s$.
But since
$$Li_0(z) = \frac{z}{1-z}$$
and
$$ \frac{\partial Li_s(z)}{\partial z} = Li_{s-1}(z)$$
we find for $s<0$ that
$$ Li_s(z) \leq Li_{\lfloor s\rfloor}(z) = \Big(\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\Big)^{\lfloor s\rfloor} \frac{z}{1-z}.$$